# Question regarding Warning

Tags: iphone

I'm writing in my code,
static const NSString *a = @"HARDIk";
this is in a.h file

now i use this,

a object in any b file
I'm getting  warning   a   defined but not used

how to remove this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the definition into the implementation (.m) file. If you want to remove the symbol `a` from another implementation file, you have to remove the `static` and put a declaration

```
extern NSString* a;
```

in your header.

Comment: I did as u said but it gives a is initialized and declare extern

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You have to write `NSString* a = @"HARDIk";` in the .m file in global scope (not in a function).

Comment: Sir i have simple question.
I have a.h file where i declare static const NSString *variable = @"HARDIk"


Now,
in b.m file 
i have function [a funtionname:(NSString*)variable];

i use this operation and it works properly but i get warning difined but not used

how to remove this warning.

is any solution for this warning?

Comment: As I said in the original answer: replace `static const NSString *variable = @"HARDIk";` with `extern NSString *variable;`. Then write `NSString *variable = @"HARDIk";` in the a.m file.

Comment: You asked 36 questions but accepted none of the answers. Please start to accept (right) answers, otherwise people will stop helping you.